# Extract an attribute table from the combination of information of three rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, export

I have three distinct raster (same area of interest) and for each pixel I need to know the information contained in raster 1, 2 and 3 and extract these values possibly in table format.

How can I do that?

Comment: As a table with three columns, nothing else, like the pixel coordinate?

Comment: Yes a table with three columns is fine. 
But actually the pixel coordinates could be useful too. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use pyqgis and read each raster into a numpy array, combine the tree arrays and write to a csv file. Add the three rasters to a map (no other layers), adjust the output csv path below and execute:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

arrays = []
for rasterlayer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For each layer added to the map
    ds = gdal.Open(rasterlayer.source()) 
    band1 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) #Read it into a numpy array
    arr = np.reshape(band1, band1.size) #Reshape it from 2D to 1D
    arrays.append(arr) #Append to arrays list

#Save it to a csv file
np.savetxt(r"/home/bera/Desktop/rasters_to_table.csv", np.array(arrays).T, delimiter=',', header="raster1,raster2,raster3", comments="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very well versed in programming. 
Is there not an easier way?
For example, I have now merged the three rasters into a single raster with 3 bands. Can I extract these values into a table, perhaps going through the raster to shape conversion?

Thanks again, 
Antonio

Comment: I have done all the programming, you just need to add the rasters to the map, adjust output csv path and press "Run script"

Answer (score 2):

If your rasters are not too large (doesn’t have too many pixels) you create a point grid from one of your rasters using the **Raster pixels to points** tool. This will add the values of your raster as a field in the point layer.

You can then add attribute fields for your other rasters using the **field calculator** with this expression:
**raster_value(layer,band,point)**
for example `raster_value( 'Raster2',1, $geometry)` returns whatever the value of band 1 of Raster2 is under each point.

To get the x and y coordinates in the CRS of your point layer you would use the field calculator with the expressions `$x` and `$y`

You can then use the **export to spreadsheet** tool to get your attribute table to a excel or .ods file. You can also copy and past from your attribute table to excel.